# Summation with Levi-Civita tensor

Tags: tensors

I am not sure how performing a summation works with the [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol).  For example, if we have

$\epsilon^{ijk} x_i x_j x_k$,

how does this look once the summation is written out in components?  Is it just

$\epsilon^{123} x_1 x_2 x_3 + \epsilon^{213} x_2 x_1 x_3 + \epsilon^{231} x_2 x_3 x_1 + + \epsilon^{321} x_3 x_2 x_1  +  \epsilon^{312} x_3 x_1 x_2   +  \epsilon^{132} x_1 x_3 x_2 ?$

After writing the $\epsilon$ symbol as $+1$ or $-1$ depending on number of times it has been permuted, this is then

$ x_1 x_2 x_3 - x_2 x_1 x_3 +   x_2 x_3 x_1 - x_3 x_2 x_1  +   x_3 x_1 x_2   - x_1 x_3 x_2  .$

Comment: You wrote 321 twice and 132 zero times, but yes, that's how it works. Your expression is equal to 0 so it's not the best example, but I'm sure you can find a non-trivial one.

Comment: Since $x_ix_jx_k$ is symmetric in $i,j,k$ (unless these are non-commuting variables), the answer will be $0$.